# Как объединить массивы по ключу

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив users_inf

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [fio] => Дехтяр Анатолий
            [nic] => Мфыо
            [avatar] => 151216092618_av.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [fio] => Тот аккаунт с которым тесты проводил
            [nic] => anatolypower2
            [avatar] => 151198353419_av.jpg
        )

)
```

И есть второй массив user_message

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [text] => Всем привет :)
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:27:55
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [text] => Ну привет коль не шутишь.
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:29:43
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [text] => опаопа
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:39:29
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [text] => gdf
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:43:56
        )

)
```

Как их объединить по id чтобы во второй массив добавилась информация по совпадению с id первого массива.

Хочу получить такое.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [fio] => Дехтяр Анатолий
            [nic] => Мфыо
            [avatar] => 151216092618_av.jpg
            [text] => Всем привет :)
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:27:55
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так.
1 массив это `$users_inf` второй это `$arraymessage`
Создал 3 пустой массив `$usersmessage_array = array();`

Ну и ниже сам код.

```
$count_arraymessage = count($arraymessage);
$count_users_inf = count($users_inf);

if($count_users_inf != 0 ) { $count_users_inf = $count_users_inf -1;}
if($count_arraymessage != 0 ) { $count_arraymessage = $count_arraymessage -1;}

for($i=0;$i<=$count_arraymessage;$i++) {

    $search_userinf = $arraymessage[$i]["id"];

    for($p=0;$p<=$count_users_inf;$p++) {

        if (in_array($search_userinf, $users_inf[$p])) {
            array_push($usersmessage_array, 
                       ['id' => $users_inf[$p]["id"],
                        'fio' => $users_inf[$p]["fio"], 
                        'nic' => $users_inf[$p]["nic"],
                        'text' => $arraymessage[$i]["text"],
                        'date' => $arraymessage[$i]["date"]
                       ]);
        }

    }

}
```

В этоге получил то что хотел.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [fio] => Дехтяр Анатолий
            [nic] => Мфыо
            [text] => Всем привет :)
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:27:55
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [fio] => Тот аккаунт с которым тесты проводил
            [nic] => anatolypower2
            [text] => Ну привет коль не шутишь.
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:29:43
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [fio] => Дехтяр Анатолий
            [nic] => Мфыо
            [text] => опаопа
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:39:29
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [fio] => Тот аккаунт с которым тесты проводил
            [nic] => anatolypower2
            [text] => gdf
            [date] => 2017-12-02 20:43:56
        )

)
```